# Ошибка при установке git "make: *** [configure] Error 127"

Tags: ubuntu, makefile

ОС XUbuntu 18.04.2 LTS 64bit, пытаюсь установит git по [инструкции](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-Git)

скачал архив git-2.20.1.tar.gz, на шаге `make configure`
получаю ошибку

```
GEN configure 
/bin/sh: 1: autoconf: not found
Makefile:2232: recipe for target 'configure' failed
make: *** [configure] Error 127
```

подскажите как исправить

Comment: «собрать из исходников» — это самоцель или задача «просто установить `git`»?

Comment: цель получить последнюю версию

Comment: Стандартные предупреждения, прежде чем описать, как прострелить себе ногу: 1) если тебе не нужна новая убер-фича X, которая появилась только в новой версии, то, вероятнее всего, она тебе не так уж и нужна... 2) прямая установка из исходников — отличный способ загадить свою систему... 3) Кроме того после самостоятельной сборки подразумевается, что ты сам должен будешь следить за всеми обновлениями/уязвимостяими итп...

Comment: Если со всем вышеперечисленным согласен, то по ошибке: написано, что не хватает `autoconf`, просто установи его `apt-get install autoconf` (от `root`'а), как тебя и просят, а лучше весь `build-essentials` сразу. По идее по зависимостям оно должно было подтянуться предыдущей командой из инструкции. она точно отработала правильно?

Comment: https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Comment: Вы зачем-то выбрали самый сложный вариант. Правильный способ тут https://git-scm.com/download/linux

Comment: И вообще в 90% случаев, для Ubuntu правильный способ получить свежую версию программы это поискать её на PPA.

Comment: @Fat-Zer, 1) согласен  2) почему установка из исходников — отличный способ загадить свою систему? 3) об этом не подумал. Предыдущая команда сработала без вывода ошибок.

Comment: @Alexey Ten, потому что где то читал что на PPA находятся старые версии которые долго не обновляются, поэтому попробовал установить из исходников.

Comment: @Ramil так бывает. Надо смотреть на версию и мейнтенера. В данном случае это git-core, т.е. официальные мейнтенеры git.

Comment: @AlexeyTen — установка из файлопомойки под названием «ppa» — ничуть не менее действенный способ загадить систему, нежели самосборка.

Comment: @Ramil, дабы не пересказывать историю в тысячный раз предлагаю ввести в гугле «make install плохо» (в качестве примера, [второй сносный ответ](https://habr.com/ru/post/130868/))… Возможные альтернативы, как уже сказали — 1) найти PPA — проблема здесь в том, что в этом случае придётся доверять и третьему лицу, который поддерживает этот PPA… 2) `checkinstall` в конце вместо `make install` — но это будет полностью игнорировать зависимости + вероятны конфликты с системными версиями пакета…

Comment: … 3) собрать `deb` пакет самому (ИМХО самый правильный, но одновременно, и самый простой, и самый сложный способ), хороших руководств по этому поводу я не встречал, но для затравки примерная последовательность действий: получаешь `dsc`, исходник, и diff'ы из новой версии своего дистрибутива, `dpkg-source -x file.dsc`, устанавливаешь зависимости, `debuild`, если повезёт и нет ошибок, то устанавливаешь готовые deb-пакеты.

Answer (score 1):

> autoconf: not found

требуется программа `autoconf` из одноимённого пакета:

```
$ sudo apt install autoconf
```

предупреждая следующую ошибку: чем устанавливать пакеты по одному, лучше сразу поставить «джентельменский набор» для компиляции. в *debian*-основных дистрибутивах это мета-пакет `build-essential`:

```
$ sudo apt install build-essential
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем за помощь!
Решил сделать так, поставил на всякий случай "джентельменский набор" 
`sudo apt install build-essential`

вместо `make install` на будущее буду использовать `checkinstall` или сам собирать пакет, а пока что установлю через PPA `sudo apt install git`, предварительно проверив версию пакета на репозитории `sudo apt-cache policy git`